# Check password before decryption

Tags: java, android, encryption

I want to decrypt a string, which is working with the right password. I tried to check the password with `if(decrypt(Password, encryptedKey).contains(Key)){` But if the PW is wrong I get the following exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
```

So is there another way to check the password?

```
    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);

    SecretKeySpec Spec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Spec);


    byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(enc);

    return new String(result);
}
```

Comment: Well, if it won't decrypt (and throws an exception) using an incorrect password, but will decrypt using the correct password, what's the problem? There isn't (or at least *shouldn't be*) an "easier" way to check the password than actually decrypting.

Comment: you mean I should use try and catch??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it won't decrypt (and throws an exception) using an incorrect password, but will decrypt using the correct password, what's the problem? There isn't (or at least *shouldn't be*) an easier way to check the password than actually decrypting: an existence of a shortcut provides a weak spot which the attacker can target ("why try each of the possible passwords when there's a password hint under the doormat?").

If it decrypts without exception, the password is correct; if you get that exception, the password is incorrect.

This may not be optimal stylistically (as in "only using exceptions for exceptional states"), but won't lower your system's security, like storing the password alongside the data would (hashing the password before storage helps *a bit*, but it's easy to get wrong, and it still increases the system's complexity while reducing its security - see e.g. [this](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.html) for a taste of the complexities involved).

Comment: That exception is not a reliable indicator of a bad password. In other word, bad passwords can still result in valid pad blocks at random, especially when the padding amount is only 1 or 2 bytes.

Comment: @GregS: Fair point. The OP should probably check that the decrypted output is meaningful - IIRC decrypting with an incorrect password (even if it doesn't break the padding) should give out garbage, right?

Comment: Well, we only get a peek into the OPs application. Any message encryption format/protocol should include a message integrity check like an HMAC, or something more modern like an AEAD cipher mode. This check will also catch a bad password.

Answer (score 2):

That would mean that your password would have to be stored somewhere in order for your program to compare it with the input password. You will have to hash that saved password is you don't want to create a backdoor for hackers. (the input password will then be hashed as well and compared to the stored password)

Comment: Ok, thanks. This string is one line of a file, so I will save the password in the file encrypted with MD5 Encryption

Comment: I'd avoid saving hash of password anywhere because that weakens your system - now the attacker only needs to break the hash first which could be potentially easier than decryption.

Comment: In this case (encrypted data), the plaintext password should ONLY be stored in the user's head ;)

Comment: @RomanPlášil What I meant, was that you need to store something to compare the login password with and that a hashed (and salted) password is much safer to store.

Comment: but we are talking about decrypting data here, not about login